# Variable declarations with get/set

Tags: c#, variable-declaration

Why do people do this

```
int myInt { get; set; }
```

rather than just this?

```
int myInt;
```

Comment: The first is a property, the second is a field. Feel free to research on the difference between them.

Comment: You should never make fields of a class visible to the outside. Field manipulation should only happen inside the class declaring the field. Access from outside only via properties. Also, using a property from the get-go makes modification easier when your myInt at some point has to do more than just store an int. Also you cannot use fields in interface definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Some code will make it simple for you to start with.
What do you prefer?

this?:

```
private int _myInt;
public int GetMyInt()
{
    return _myInt;
}
public void SetMyInt(int value)
{
    _myInt = value;
}
```

or this?:

```
int myInt { get; set;}
```

Properties makes it easy. you can read more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).